# Undo a Merged Pull Request and the Conflict Resolution

Tags: git, azure-devops

We've run into an annoying case when using the Azure DevOps Repositories:

We have two working branches:
-Branch A
-Branch B

And a target Branch
-Branch Dev

What we did:

1. PR from Branch A -> Branch Dev
2. PR from Branch B -> Branch Dev -> Caused Merge Conflict due to changes from Branch A

We then solved the Merge Conflict and completed the second Pull Request. However we accidentally resolved the Conflict in an undesired way.

Now here comes the question:

Can we revert the Conflict resolution?

We were able to revert the second Pull request of cause and by reverting it again to push the same changes back to Branch Dev. However that caused no Merge Conflict, thus we could not undo our bad decisions of the past.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: If by *revert the second Pull request* you mean you created a new commit using `git revert`, then you won't be able to merge the branch again, and you won't be able to correct your bad resolution. If circumstances allow to rewrite history, you can reset the dev branch before the bad merge and repeat it. Otherwise, you can only make a new commit with the topic "Oops, we made a blunder, and this fixes it".

Comment: For now we just did a new commit.